# Input1 value is undefiend, how to use this in the function?

Tags: javascript, function, scope

I have a file **data.js** which requires certain files from outside, I am getting the values by iterating the array, my aim is to use the values inside other function which is out of scope.

Please see the comments.

**data.js**

```
var input1;
var input2;

var config = require('./somefile.js');
var i;
for(i=0; i<config.anything.length; i++){
    input1 = config.anything[i].something; //---line1
    input2 = config.anything[i].everything;//---line2
}
var data = function(input1, input2)// how to get the same value for input1 & input2 as similar in line1 & 2? so that I can use these in my function `data`.

{
   //I want to use these values inside my function.
  console.log('input1 value', input1); //displays as undefined !
}
```

Comment: how are you calling `data`  function? the global declared variables are far different from the arguments of the function!!

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

1. Import the somefile.js first as this needs to be done in the first line
2. Define the variables which should used in this code. I preferred declaring them using comma separation
3. Make a call to the implement function to read the data fetched from somefile.js and push the data in the array input1 and input 2
4. finally make a call to the function data() to print the data

**data.js**

```
    // Modified data.js     

    var config = require('./somefile.js'),
            input1 = [], //these should be declared as arrays as they store collection data
            input2 = [], //these should be declared as arrays as they store collection data 
            i;
        console.log("config is     " + config.getAnything());

        //declare a callback function and call the data in the callback
        implement();

        function implement() {
            var configData = config.getAnything(),
                len = configData.length;
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                input1.push(configData[i].something); //---line1
                input2.push(configData[i].everything); //---line2
            }
            console.log('input1 value', input1);
            data();
        }
        //function call
        function data() {
            console.log('input1 value', input1);
        }
```

Modified somefile.js with comments:

1. Declare the variable to define a blank array
2. run a for loop topopulate the collection
3. finally expose the function getAnything through exports so that it can be used in any other file.

**somefile.js**

```
//Modified somefile.js 
var anything = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var obj = {
    something: 'something' + i,
    everything: 'everthing' + i
  }
  anything.push(obj);
}
console.log(anything);
exports.getAnything = function() {
  return anything;
}
```

Comment: Added a suggested implementation for the above implementation. If you have any questions on this feel free to post them

Comment: Nice suggestion, but it could be better to provide an explanation ;)

Comment: I shall get back with some suggestions

Comment: Re added the solution back with some code comments. See if this helps

Comment: You shouldn't add it as another answer, but as an edit to your actual answer, and add the explanation as etxt in the post instead of comments in the code. :)

Comment: Ok Will keep in mind for future answers. Thank you for good suggestions

Answer (score 0):

```
// data.js added with comments     
/** 1. Import the somefile.js first as this needs to be done in the first line 
     *  2. Define the variables which should used in this code. I preferred declaring them using comma 
     *     separation 
     *  3. Make a call to the implement function to read the data fetched from somefile.js and push the 
     *     data in the array input1 and input 2
     *  4. finally make a call to the function data() to print the data
     */

    var config = require('./somefile.js'),
        input1 = [], //these should be declared as arrays as they store collection data
        input2 = [], //these should be declared as arrays as they store collection data 
        i;
    console.log("config is     " + config.getAnything());

    //declare a callback function and call the data in the callback
    implement();

    function implement() {
        var configData = config.getAnything(),
            len = configData.length;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            input1.push(configData[i].something); //---line1
            input2.push(configData[i].everything); //---line2
        }
        console.log('input1 value', input1);
        data();
    }
    //function call
    function data() {
        console.log('input1 value', input1);
    }

// Modified somefile.js with comments
/** 1. Declare the variable to define a blank array 
 *  2. run a for loop topopulate the collection 
 *  3. finally expose the function getAnything through exports so that it can be 
 *     used in any other file
 */

var anything = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var obj = {
        something: 'something' + i,
        everything: 'everthing' + i
    }
    anything.push(obj);
}
console.log(anything);
exports.getAnything = function() {
    return anything;
}
```

Comment: You should now just delete this answer.